# Deploy commands script for discordjs not ending

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have the following, a slight modification from the guides version [here](https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/main/code-samples/creating-your-bot/command-deployment/deploy-commands.js)

```
const commands = [];
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    // Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    // Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = await import(filePath);
        if ('commandObject' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            commands.push(command.commandObject.commandInfo);
        } else {
            console.warn(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

// Construct and prepare an instance of the REST module
const rest = new REST().setToken(botToken);

// and deploy your commands!
(async() => {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);
        // The put method is used to fully refresh all commands in the guild with the current set
        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands }
        );

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

The script does not end after the commands are successfully reloaded. The promise is being resolved as the `Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.` log is outputted, but then it stays open from here and I am at a loss as to why.

Comment: I have a few questions. Why are `__filename` and `__dirname` being redefined? Are you `botToken`, `clientId` ,`guildId` hardcoded when you are running it on your machine? There appear to be some changes with how you define each `command.js` in your commands folder, could you include those? Though none of these seem to be related to the issue you are having. When I set up the example you linked, my program promptly closes after printing the success message.

Comment: @0mlml `__dirname` and `__filename` are not defined in ES modules so those are not redefined.